# Python api request won't work eventhough i got pip on the right path

Tags: python, pip

I'm very new to python so I probably have made a coding fault, but what im trying to do is use GET to retrieve data from a website. My code is as following:

`import requests`

`r = requests`

`r.GET = 'http://example.com/hi/there?hand=wave'`

`print(r)`

Pycharm returns the following in the console:

```
C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\PhoneNumberRequest\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/PhoneNumberRequest/venv/Scripts/ApiRequest.py
<module 'requests' from 'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\PhoneNumberRequest\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\__init__.py'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Isn't it supposed to give back the data that comes with the API?
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you mean `request = r.GET('http://example.com/hi/there?hand=wave')`?

Comment: Yes thats the solution. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you should rather write

```
result *(or whatever)* = r.GET('http://example.com/hi/there?hand=wave')
```

since you don't want to set the value of r.GET(...) but of a new variable that contains the result/response.